# Port issues when accessing mysql and wordpress on docker

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, phpmyadmin

Fairly new to docker so would appreciate some help with the port set up please :)

This is the docker-compose.yml script I've been using to create the containers.

```
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:4.6
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content 
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - back
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - back
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - back
networks:
  back:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

It consists of PhpMyadmin, MySql and Wordpress.

I am able to access PhpMyAdmin using the docker default ip with ':8080' however i'm encountering issues when trying to call out to wordpress or mysql and I'm not sure why. I've tried to set the port for both and access this but have been unable to.

[image: The containers with the port]

Error message when trying to access:

[image: Error Message on safari]

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, where are you trying to reach which service from? if host to sql, you'll need to open port 3306.

Comment: Yes its from the docker host to mysql and to wordpress. how do i go about opening the port?

Comment: same as you've done with ports: - 8080:80, but 3306:3306

Comment: Your log does not talk about network creation? at end of file i can't see on network creation the definition about network type. External or any type, like bridge, for example.